# How do I open react-native popup-menu from a <TouchableOpacity> that is from another function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I'm creating a React-native app, which has a question-answer system, and this menu is intended for confirming a chosen answer.

How can I open react-native-popup-menu without having a separate Menutrigger?

```
        <Menu renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu}>
            <MenuTrigger>
                <Text>
                    {answers}
                </Text>
            </MenuTrigger>
                <MenuOptions>
                    <MenuOption>
                        <View>
                            <h2> {title}</h2>
                            <h3> {text}</h3>
                        </View>
                    </MenuOption>
                    <MenuOption>

                    <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                        <Button title= "CANCEL" onPress={onCancel}/>
                        <Button title= "CONTINUE" onPress={onConfirm}/>
                    </View>

                    </MenuOption>
                </MenuOptions>
        </Menu>
```

);

In this code the "{answers} trigger activates when I push a button, and the {answers} then become the button that triggers the menu which then triggers the title and the body to slide in. How can I trigger the title and the body without getting the extra step in?

Comment: Did you try to put the `MenuTrigger` outside of `Menu`?

Comment: It is necessary that <MenuTrigger /> is a direct child of <Menu />, According to the API.

Comment: Are you using Adobe Spectrum?

Comment: Never heard of it, so no.

Comment: What component library are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/

Comment: Is this the behaviour you need?: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-carson-mg3d7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No, the example you provided still needed the text trigger. What I'm looking for is a way for the menu to trigger from the other function. In the example you provided, imagine a button in App. I'm looking for a way for that button to trigger the menu.

Comment: https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/MenuMethodsExample.js